# Docker build: Failed to compute cache key: not found, docker build context broken?

Tags: dockerfile

The function ADD and COPY in my Dockerfile works remotely, but not for local files.

I tested it on a minimal setup to avoid any mistake. Is there any way to find out what is the problem?
[Minimal setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHRqI.png)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue! `COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock
COPY vendor vendor <-- this breaks`

Comment: The issues was having it in `.gitignore`. That prevented `COPY` to work.